# How do I remove the 'mesh' in the starter blend file?

Tags: modeling

So in the starter blend file, there is a cube, and there is this mesh thing underneath it. I deleted the cube, and made my own creation, but I can't figure out how delete that mesh. I need to delete because I made a greenscreened plane, and the mesh is interfering. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the [grid floor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html?highlight=grid%20floor)?

Comment: You can turn off all overlays at the top right-ish of the 3D view also

Answer (score 1):

go to the tab on the right, scroll down to "display" and uncheck "grid floor", "y" , and "x", to remove the entire grid. 
[image]